# type in routes on angular-ui-router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm playing around with [this demo](https://github.com/Foxandxss/GermanWords-ng1-webpack) of the angular-ui-router using a WordPress site to host the javascript file (which isn't intended by the app author but demonstrates my problem nonetheless). The angular app has a `/login` route, which, if I click the link to on the homepage, loads the `login` template of the angular app. However, if I type in the url `http://localhost:8888/login` it shows the WordPress login page i.e. it's not handled by the angular-ui-router, which makes it kind of useless/unpredictable as a router.

Question: Is there a way to get angular-ui-router to handle a route that's typed in the browser, or is there an angular router that will handle typed in routes in the browser?

Background: I was going to use angular as a front-end for a WordPress site and it's pretty important that it be able to handle routes dropped in the browser, for example, for `http:localhost:8888/2015/10/10/my-wordpress-post`

This is the code that handles the `login` route

```
'use strict'; 
2 

3 routes.$inject = ['$stateProvider']; 
4 

5 export default function routes($stateProvider) { 
6   $stateProvider 
7     .state('login', { 
8       url: '/login', 
9       template: require('./login.html'), 
10       controller: 'LoginController', 
11       controllerAs: 'login' 
12     }); 
13 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your server is listening for url-based requests. If you're on an Angular page and click a link, you're using HTML5 push-state. If you type in a URL, you're not, your server handles it before the angular ever does. The easiest solution would be to install the Wordpress app in a subdirectory, and use the root to serve an Angular app.

Comment: so use some other type of application to serve the angular app in the root? For example, it could be a python application even?  keep them completely separate?

Comment: Yes, though it'd probably be easier to just let PHP do it if you're already using PHP for the wordpress. Otherwise you'd have to figure out an easy way to have different webservers listen on different paths.

Comment: And when I say PHP, I mean apache.

Comment: Here's a link to an .htaccess file that looks like it would work: https://gist.github.com/rayfranco/3211654

Comment: so are these the instructions you'd use to have WordPress in its own directory? https://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory? If so, would you still follow instruction 7 and copy the index.php into the root directory (so it exists in two places)?

Comment: Those are instructions to install wordpress in a subdirectory and still have it run as if it were from the root. You don't really want that. You want it to work in a subdirectory only, and then you're writing your own front-end that runs on root. Just put it in a subdirectory and do a normal install.

Comment: I'm guessing that `.htaccess` file you linked to won't let me login via `http:localhost/wordpress/wp-admin/` because it'll serve index.html. Do you know how you'd change the .htaccess file to leave a path to a login via the server?

Comment: It's been a while, but I think you could use `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wp-admin/.*$`