# .htaccess for single page app in wordpress

Tags: angularjs, wordpress, .htaccess

I have a single page Angular app built using Wordpress and the JSON API. The site uses Angular UI router, so the URLs are configured through HTML5 push state.

Using the HTML5 true mode in Angular in order to remove the /#/ character from the URL, pages on the angular app are displayed correctly when they are navigated to via the index page, but they do not display when you type in a URL or refresh the page. Instead the site navigates to a related Wordpress post. The issue is similar to this Stackoverflow post [type in routes on angular-ui-router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33108245/type-in-routes-on-angular-ui-router)

Please help!

Comment: Not enough known about where your app root is vs wordpress install or how current htaccess is configured and where

Comment: You actually provided no info or code on your current setup and how things are being handled now. Impossible to help you with just a description.